# How to get Enterprise Manager installed in SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I've installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express twice now, and all the services work and I can create databases from Visual Studio 2010, but I don't have the ***Enterprise Manager*** (I learned it is now called ***Management Studio***) available in the SQL Server 2008 program menu-- I do have other menu items like configuration manager, etc. but nothing for *Management Studio / Enterprise Manager*.

Is there a checkbox I've missed during installation?
I ran a search for all exes in the SQL Server root folder and nothing jumped out as belonging to the Enterprise Manager, but I'm not 100% sure what the executable would be named.

Primary question:
    What is the procedure required to install the Management Studio client [for/with SQL 2008 Express] ?
Secondary question:
    What is the name of this client's executable file ?

Comment: It's called Management Studio now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server Express doesn't come with SQL Server Management Studio (what you are really looking for when you say Enterprise Manager).  You have to download it separately:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593

or with tools already as part of the download

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22973

Comment: Some installation packages for SQL Express actually include the Management Studio (for example the "With Tools" installer), but this "Studio only", lightweight package can be quite useful.

Answer (score 6):

It's kind of tricky installing Management Studio. [This article](http://www.asql.biz/Articoli/SQLX08/Art1_2.aspx) walks you through it.

Here is an [explanation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/8a5ff5b7-1098-41a5-b9a1-417f102ae441) of the situation:

The 2008 version of the Management Studio is not a stand alone installation and can only be installed as part of the SQL Server 2008 Express with Tools or Advanced installation.

> Like many others, I spent countless hours trying to figure out how to
>   install the Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 Express - Advanced
>   installation (same should apply to the w/ Tools version).  What
>   happened in my case was that I installed Visual Studio 2008 Express
>   and during that process a stripped down "Instance" of SQL Server 2008
>   was installed that did not include the Management Studio.  Through
>   much pain and torture I learned that the Management Studio can only be
>   installed during installation of the first instance. To delete that
>   first instance, you must go to "Add or Remove Programs" and remove
>   "Microsoft SQL Server 2008".  The removal process will only remove one
>   instance at a time and if you have installed more than one instance
>   you need to keep going until all instances have been removed and the
>   application completely disappears from the Add or Remove Programs"
>   dialog.  Note: You do not need to uninstall any of the other SQL
>   Server 2008 applications that also appear in the "Add or Remove
>   Programs" dialog.  Then go back through the install process as
>   follows: Double click on SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe to load the SQL Server
>   Installation Center and then go to Installation > New SQL Server
>   stand-alone installation.  Then proceed through all of the
>   installation steps until you get to “Feature Selection” and click on
>   “Select All” to toggle on all of the Shared Features, which should
>   include Management Tools - Basic.Continue the process from there and
>   you should be good to go.  Hopefully this will help others to avoid
>   much of the pain that many of us have already experienced.

The Management Studio exe is named ssms.exe.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is not alone in his puzzlement about the "missing" management client!!! ;-)
The answers by `DOK` and `CD Jorgensen` found here were -collectively- among the most helpful I found while searching the web on this particular issue!  At the risk of being redundant, I'm adding this answer with the goal of being more explicit and of safeguarding the key screenshots from Andrea Montanari's article referenced in DOK's answer.

Two things to know:

- **Not all installation packages for SQL Server 2008 Express Edition include the Management Studio.**
  You either need to ... 
  `a)` ... download the [**Install package for SQL Server 2008 Express *with Tools***](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22973) (named something like SQLEXPRWT_cpu_language.exe:  note the `WT`, short for ***With Tools***) or an installer for an Edition of SQL Server other than Express.
  or
  `b)` ...download the [**Installer specific to Microsoft SQL Management Studio Express**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593) (same link as provided by CD Jorgensen).  This installer only contains the Management Studio; it has none of the SQL Server *per se*.
- [if you go with an `a)` install package]
  The Management Studio (formerly Enterprise Manager) client remains a *stand-alone*, independent, component.  However **its installation is now triggered from a selection made *as part of the "Install or Modify SQL Server" track.***
  It is not found in a separate "Install clients and Tools" menu item from the topmost dialog of the installer (as was the case with SQL 2005 and previous versions).
  One should stress that it *is* stand-alone and the client can indeed be installed on hosts where the SQL Server [engine] is not, and will not be, installed at all. However the initial steps in the Installation Wizard give a strong impression that we will effectively install or re-install SQL Server. It is only on a subsequent step labelled `Feature Selection` that we have the ability to select `Management Tools` under `Shared Features`.  On that same Feature Selection dialog we have the option of including or excluding, as desired, the installation of the SQL Server Engine and other *Server* supporting modules.

These are the two key dialogs of the wizard with regards to this issue:
The first one really appears to put you on track to install or *mess with* the SQL Server itself, the other dialog finally provides the opportunity of opting for the Client Tools (which include, mainly, the Management Studio).  This same dialog also allows checking or un-checking the selection to install the Server per se.

[image: Commented screenShots of Installation Wizard]

**Credits and more info**:
The screenshots were taken from [Andrea Montanari's article](http://www.asql.biz/Articoli/SQLX08/Art1_2.aspx) on the Insulin Power web site. This article referenced in DOK's answer provides a step-by-step description of the installation based on the "With Tools" installer.
As said in the introduction, I learned much from [CD Jorgensen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8917355/166686) and [DOK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8917377/166686)'s answers; I'm merely making a few things more explicit, here, and correcting a few omissions (e.g. there are some installers which carry both the Server and the client, and it is not necessary to install the server).