# How do I install Management Studio on my local machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I am attempting to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition on my local machine for development learning purposes. I am running windows 32bit vista (unfortunately) .

So far I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Express with Management Tools from this link:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=23650

However when I go to Start > SQL Server 2008 R2

All I see is the following:

[image]

I expect to see Management Studio here also so that I can connect to my local sql server create a DB and run queries etc but as you can see there is nothing here other than Import and Export Data.

I have also tried going to back to installation manager but cannot find the management studio installer.

When I click add node to SQL Server failover cluster I get 3 failures:

**Cluster_IsMachineClustered**

**Cluster_IsOnline**

**Cluster_VerifyForErrors**

Not sure what the relevence of this is or even if this is the right place to try to install SSMS?

In terms of services currently running, when I go to configuration manager I see the following:

[image]

**Questions**

1.)Does it look as if I have a local instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 installed and running on my machine?

2.)How do I install Management Studio 2008 R2 on my machine so that I can create a DB etc on my local SQL Server 2008 R2.

**edit**

When I follow the link provided below and download and Run the installer I get the following:

[image]

**edit 2**
I got passed the error message (Because I had ie open) then it opened SQL Server Installation Centre, I clicked Installation > New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation.

This is the features screen I was presented with, still no Management Studio, I dont understand how I am meant to get this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link may help you:  [How to get Enterprise Manager installed in SQL Server 2008 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917315/how-to-get-enterprise-manager-installed-in-sql-server-2008-express?rq=1)

And, it looks as if you have two instances on your machine, one called SQLEXPRESS and the other called MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: Please see my edit above, I clicked the link on the accepted answer found on the link you provided, selected SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe and clicked Run, then got the error in the image.

Comment: This fellow says that this happens if you have Internet Explorer open when doing that:  http://www.ingmarverheij.com/sql-invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has-been-created/.  There is also this Microsoft fix:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975055

Comment: Okay I got past the error, thanks for directing me to the explaination. What happens next is it merely opens SQL Server Installation Center, what do I do from here? This is where I originally came to install SQL Server 2008 R2, im confused and frustrated with how difficult they have made to get your hands on the management studio tools!?

Comment: That is very odd.  I just tried that download myself and found that it did show me "Management Tools" under "Shared Features".  Let me experiment some more.

Comment: Here's another link:  this person says to try the Web Platform Installer.  It sounds like a lot of people are having this problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957949/sql-server-management-studio-missing-after-2008-r2-install

Comment: Is it possible to have SSMS2008R2 with only an express edition of SQL Server?

Comment: I found out where I was going wrong, I was selecting ADD FEATURES, when I needed to select Perform a New Installation.
Link here which explained: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Thanks for your help!

Comment: YAY for solutions!  I'm glad!